# SQLITE: How to make indexing work for you?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, query-optimization

I have a sqlite db of employees with about a million entries.

```
company:

emp_id(primary) | first_name | last_name | company_name | job_title
```

The db contains only 10 distinct company names (i.e. let's say each company has about 100k employees)
I created an index on company name:

```
CREATE INDEX cmp_name ON company(company_name)
```

But I have not gained any speed while performing query:

WITH INDEX:

```
select * from company INDEXED BY cmp_name where company_name = 'XYZ corp';
Time: 88.45 sec
```

WITHOUT INDEX:

```
select * from company where company_name = 'XYZ corp';
Time: 89.12 sec
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are still selecting 100.000 rows, the index won't make that part faster magically. Do you see a difference for `select count(*)` ?

Comment: @Thilo How can I modify my index to gain speed?

Comment: So you work for a organization with 1 million employees, but you're stuck using sqlite as the relational db? Not oracle, postgresql, or sql server?

Comment: The actual scenario is different. I used employees as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database is organized into pages. If more than ten rows fit into a page, then on average, reading all the "XYZ Corp" rows still requires reading most pages. Furthermore, with the index entries not having the same order as the table rows, the table's page are no longer read in order.

The only way to speed up this query would be to use a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx). First, reduce the number of columns read to the absolute minimum that you actually need, then add all those columns to the company name index (the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is implicitly part of every index):

```
CREATE INDEX cmp_name_and_other_stuff ON company(company_name, last_name);

SELECT emp_id, last_name FROM company WHERE company_name = 'XYZ Corp';
```

Doing this for every query will waste lots of storage space.

Comment: Does that mean, if I want to create a search query for 5 columns, I should create an index with all those 5 columns?

Comment: No. A single-column index that reduces the number of table pages to be read works just fine. Furthermore, an index can be used only if lookups are done on all its leftmost columns.

Comment: But I don't understand 1 thing you said: Reading of company name will still require reading of most of the pages. But If I have indexed the db based on company name, shouln't it read only the 1/10th pages i.e. only the (indexed)pages that have been indexed by XYZ corporation?

Comment: Only if the rows with that company happen to be stored in the same pages, i.e., if the table is accidentally sorted by company.

Comment: You can get some improvement by just including the primary key (emp_id) in the index, but an index that covers will be better.